# Windows paths in Python strings

Tags: python, string, windows, path

I'm developing a program for Windows platforms using Python, and it needs to open CSV files in order to process them. My problem is that it doesn't matter how I try, when I pass the path inside a string variable to the open function, it will fail because of the double backslash thing Python does in strings. I have tried with `os.path.join` and raw strings, and it doesn't solve the problem.

Here is one of the pieces of code where this is happening, so you can see the problem in real code:

```
def readRank(name):
    data_list_ind = []
    data_list_group = []
    with open(os.path.join(
              os.getcwd(), name, name + '_ind.csv'), 'rb') as fRank:
        reader = csv.reader(fRank)
        rowNum = 0
        for row in reader:
            if rowNum == 0 or row[0] == '': # First row is just the headers
                rowNum += 1
                continue
            data_row = []

            for col in row:
                data_row.append(col)

            data_list_ind.append(data_row)
            rowNum += 1
```

This code is throwing an error such as: "Couldn't find file 'C:\\Whatever\\the\\path\\is'".

How could I solve this?

Comment: This works fine on my machine. Are you sure the path is correct and you have stored the CSV in a subfolder specified by `name`.

Comment: Yes, the error I put was wrong, now it is as it appears, apparently I have the same trouble with backslashes in stackoverflow

Comment: The error message shows the repr of the path, which uses escaped backslashes. There's no problem there. Please provide the actual error with a traceback.

Answer (score -1):

One thing could try is to use '/' instead of '\'

Comment: This is not how a proper answer should look like. Either you are confident of the solution or not. This should be a comment.

Comment: Sorry will take care of that from next time